# how to fix this error in my register form

Tags: php, html

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/rsegomyu/public_html/registrations/userregister_action.php:42) in /home/rsegomyu/public_html/registrations/userregister_action.php on line 116

My site now online but fist time i fill the register form it's successfully registered but after i add my form to date-time field.some one fill this form and hi submit the form then register date and time automatically save in my database.
 but my website going on server but server sql time and my pc current time is different.but i contact host company and they create some page and they say now check it.but it's not work.
And other error is i write some scrip to popup the message to show the registration successful then after this error message came.place help my some one
thank you

this is my registration.php page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.galleriffic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.opacityrollover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function() { 
    $("html").niceScroll();
    }
    );
    </script><!-- nice scroll end-->
</head>
<body id="page1">
    <!--==============================header=================================-->
    <header>
        <div class="row-1">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="container_12">
                    <div class="grid_12">
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li><a  href="index.php">About Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="catalogue.html">Catalogue</a></li>
                                <li><a  href="contacts.php">Contacts</a></li>
                                <li><a class="active" href="registration.php">Registration</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-2">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="container_12">
                    <div class="grid_9">
                        <h1>
                            <a class="logo" href="index.html">1<strong>2</strong>4Docs</a>
                            <span>Design</span>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_3">
                        <!--<form id="search-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="search-field">
                                    <input name="search" type="text" />
                                  <a class="search-button" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit()"><span>search</span></a>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>-->
                     </div>
                     <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
<!-- content -->
    <section id="content">
        <div class="bg-top">
            <div class="bg-top-2">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="bg-top-shadow">
                        <div class="main">
                            <div class="container_12">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <article class="grid_12">
                                        <h3 class="color-1">Registration Form</h3>
                                        <div class="wrapper">
                   <!--message Box-->
                   <div style="color:#090; font-size:14px; text-align:center;">
            <?php
                        if(isset($_REQUEST['msg'])) {
                    echo base64_decode($_REQUEST['msg']);
                    }
                    ?>
                    </div>
                     <!--message Box-->
               <form id="contact-form" class="form-group" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="registrations/userregister_action.php">
                <label id="lbl"><span class="text-form2">Full Name</span>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" name="fullname" required/></label>
                <label id="lbl"><span class="text-form2">Address</span>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Address" name="address" required/></label>
                <label id="lbl"><span class="text-form2">Email</span>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" required/></label>
                 <label id="lbl"><span class="text-form2">NIC</span>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="NIC" name="nic" required/></label>
                <label id="lbl"><span class="text-form2">Telephone No</span>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Telephone No" name="telephone_no" required/></label>
                <label id="lbl"><span class="text-form2">Loan Type</span>
                <select class="form-control" name="loantype" required="required">
                <option value="">Please Select Your Loan Type</option>
                <option value="Home">Home Loan</option>
                <option value="Personal">Personal Loan</option>
                </select></label>
                <label id="lbl"><span class="text-form2">Bank</span>
                <select class="form-control" name="bank" required="required">
                <option value="">Please Select Bank</option>
                <option value="BOC">BOC</option>
                <option value="NSB">NSB</option>
                <option value="RDB">RDB</option>
                <option value="PEOPLES">People's Bank</option>
                <option value="SEYLAN">Seylan</option>
                </select></label>
                <label id="lbl"><span class="text-form2">Loan Value (Laks)</span>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" name="amount" required/></label>
                <label id="lbl"><span class="text-form2">Upload Your Plan Images (.pdf)</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="plan_file" required/></label>
                <p id="adslip">Advance Slip</p>
                <label id="lbl"><span class="text-form2">Payment Slip Upload (.png or .jpeg)</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="payment_slip_url" required/></label>
                <div class="buttons">
                <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="REGISTER" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">
                <input class="form-control" type="reset" value="CLEAR" id="btn">
            </form>
                </div>
                      </div>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--==============================footer=================================-->
    <footer>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="grid_6">
                        <div>OneTwoFour-Docs &copy; 2018 <a class="link color-3" href="#">Privacy Policy</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_6" align="right">
                    Created By PerlTech Solutions
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
            // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
            $('div.navigation').css({'width' : '320px', 'float' : 'right'});
            $('div.content').css('display', 'block');
            // Initially set opacity on thumbs and add
            // additional styling for hover effect on thumbs
            var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.5;
            $('#thumbs ul.thumbs li span').opacityrollover({
                mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
                mouseOverOpacity:  0.0,
                fadeSpeed:         'fast',
                exemptionSelector: '.selected'
            });
            // Initialize Advanced Galleriffic Gallery
            var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
                delay:                     7000,
                numThumbs:                 12,
                preloadAhead:              6,
                enableTopPager:            false,
                enableBottomPager:         false,
                imageContainerSel:         '#slideshow',
                controlsContainerSel:      '',
                captionContainerSel:       '',
                loadingContainerSel:       '',
                renderSSControls:          true,
                renderNavControls:         true,
                playLinkText:              'Play Slideshow',
                pauseLinkText:             'Pause Slideshow',
                prevLinkText:              'Prev',
                nextLinkText:              'Next',
                nextPageLinkText:          'Next',
                prevPageLinkText:          'Prev',
                enableHistory:             true,
                autoStart:                 7000,
                syncTransitions:           true,
                defaultTransitionDuration: 900,
                onSlideChange:             function(prevIndex, nextIndex) {
                    // 'this' refers to the gallery, which is an extension of $('#thumbs')
                    this.find('ul.thumbs li span')
                        .css({opacity:0.5})
                },
                onPageTransitionOut:       function(callback) {
                    this.find('ul.thumbs li span').css({display:'block'});
                },
                onPageTransitionIn:        function() {
                    this.find('ul.thumbs li span').css({display:'none'});
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my userregister_action.php code

```
<?php
session_start();
$msg="";
include 'db_connection.php';
$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$nic=$_POST['nic'];
$telephone_no=$_POST['telephone_no'];
$loantype=$_POST['loantype'];
$bank=$_POST['bank'];
$amount=$_POST['amount'];
$plan_file=basename($_FILES["plan_file"]["name"]);
$payment_slip_url=basename($_FILES["payment_slip_url"]["name"]);
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//$job_description_img_url = basename($_FILES["job_description_img_url"]["name"]);
$sql= "INSERT INTO user_register (fullname,address,email,nic,telephone_no,loantype,bank,amount,plan_file,payment_slip_url,dateposted) VALUES ('$fullname','$address','$email','$nic','$telephone_no','$loantype','$bank','$amount','$plan_file','$payment_slip_url',NOW())";
//slip add START
        $folder = "payment_slip/";
        $file = $folder.basename($_FILES["payment_slip_url"]["name"]);
        //$success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["payment_slip_url"]["tmp_name"],$file);
        $ok=1;
$file_type=$_FILES['payment_slip_url']['type'];
if ($file_type=="image/png" || $file_type=="image/jpeg") {
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['payment_slip_url']['tmp_name'], $file))
{
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['payment_slip_url']['name']). " is uploaded";
}
else {
echo "Problem uploading file";
}
}
else {
echo "You may only upload JPEGs or PNG files.<br>";
//$msg=base64_encode("You may only upload JPEGs or PNG for Payment Slip");
}
//slip add END
//plan add START
$folder = "plans/";
$file = $folder.basename($_FILES["plan_file"]["name"]);
//$success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["payment_slip_url"]["tmp_name"],$file);
$ok=1;
$file_type=$_FILES['plan_file']['type'];
if ($file_type=="application/pdf") {
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['plan_file']['tmp_name'], $file))
{
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['plan_file']['name']). " is uploaded";
 }
 else {
 echo "Problem uploading file";
 }
}
else {
//echo "You may only upload PDFs.<br>";
$msg=base64_encode("You may only upload PDFs for Plan Images");
}
//plan add END
if (mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)){
    //echo "OK";
    //$msg=base64_encode("Successfully Registered");
    $msg=base64_encode('Successfully Registered');
//}else{
    //echo "NO";
    //$msg=base64_encode("Please enter your details correctly");
//}
if($msg!=""){
//Redirection
header("Location:../registration.php?msg=$msg");
exit();
    }
}
else{
$msg=mysqli_error($dbcon);
}
?>
```

And This is the error show in my after the register

(The file user.png is uploadedThe file sheet 1.pdf is uploaded
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/rsegomyu/public_html/registrations/userregister_action.php:42) in /home/rsegomyu/public_html/registrations/userregister_action.php on line 116)

Comment: add `ob_start()` at the top of your page and `ob_end_flush()` at the end. try if it works!

Comment: Ok, i will check it and tell you thank you and place tell me that code i need to add inside the php tag?

Comment: i have added an answer below to specify what i meant.

Comment: It's Work Thank you very much fried and i need to know we use that code now error is fix how is it work place explain me it's very helpfully thank you again

Comment: `ob_start()` keeps on remembering everything that would normally be outputted whereas `ob_end_flush()` discards everything which was saved.

Comment: Friends did you know why my server database time is efferent in my current time so how to fix it help my place some one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  ob_start();
    // your register.php script
  ob_end_flush();
?>
```

let me know if problem persists.

Comment: Friends did you know why my server database time is efferent in my current time so how to fix it help my place

Comment: you have to change your default timezone in xampp (or whichever server you are using) to the one you are currently in. google how to change timezone in xampp.

Answer (score 0):

i think both files have uploaded successfully. ob_start and ob_end_flush should do it.

Comment: i use" ob_start(); ob_end_flush()" two code in my php page top and bottom

Comment: so is it working good? bdw its to use files loop than blocks..just a advise.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this.

```
<?php
@ob_clean(); 
@ob_start();

include("some.php");

?>
```

ob_clean for clean the output buffer and ob_start for Output buffers are stackable.